Matching a fixed position in a string using C++ regex
Do C++ regular expressions have a way to refer to a fixed position within a string? I am looking for a notation that is (fictitiously) shown in the following example as @n, where n is the index of the next character:
string = "hello12345";
re = "([a-z]+[0-9]+)(@7)(.+)";
// Match: ["hello12","345"]

Update: I cannot just repeat a fixed number of characters because I do not know how many of them will match [a-z] and [0-9].

You can skip over a fixed number of characters with .{n} where n is the number of characters to skip.

It's not clear what you mean by that match. A regexp always matches a contiguous string. What do the ... represent?

@Barmar I cannot just repeat a fixed number of characters, because I do not know how many of them will match [a-z] and [0-9]. See the updated example.

([a-z]{6}\d{1}|[a-z]{5}\d{2}|[a-z]{4}\d{3}|[a-z]{3}\d{4}|[a-z]{2}\d{5}|[a-z]{1}\d{6})(.+)? Demo

Do you have to do it in a single regexp? Why not just get the substring of the first 7 characters, and check that it matches [a-z]+[0-9]+)

It's always good to get some (complicated) edge case example strings and what you'd like to match/not match/capture/not capture when talking about regexes.

@Demo Works for two parts, doesn't work (scales up exponentially) for more.

My name is not Demo ;-)

@Barmar, I guess you are right; this would work.  Thanks for the workaround. Does this mean that the answer to my question is negative? (There is no built-in mechanism for tabulation?)

On a sidenote: I've found regexes in C++ to only be useful when I want to allow a user to have some search or filtering options. If I know what I want to search for when I compile the program, writing that search from scratch is in my experience easier to get robust and it's always faster.

@Jarod42 My apologies.

@TedLyngmo I am not in a position to choose.

@DYZ I tried to come up with a solution using lookaheads and .{7}. But I couldn't ensure that the [a-z]+[0-9]+ match was entirely inside the first 7 characters.

@Barmar I tried lookaheads, too.

So I think Jarod42's method is the only way, and you'll get combinatorial explosion if the initial pattern is more complex.

@Barmar I will accept your answer to split the string and test it piecewise if you post it.

regular expressions: Now you have two problems

@Barmar As I said, I am not in a position to choose.

@DYZ If you are allowed to split the string once, are you allowed to split it twice? Thrice?

Which is the expected answer for "abcdefgh12"? Note that your regex doesn't have anchor ^. With my comment, it is accepted ignoring first letters; current solutions reject completely.

@Jarod42 The expected answer is no match because there are no digits in the first seven characters of the string, which will be confirmed after taking the substring "abcdegf" and attempting to match it.

^(?=\D{1,6}\d)([a-z\d]{7})(.+) would be another idea but I guess this does not fit your notation-requirement. However, worth to mention.

@bobblebubble Your proposed solution does not guarantee that there are exactly seven symbols in the capture group.

@DYZ Where does it not? I shared the demo. The first group captures [a-z\d]{7} the second captures .+ (one or more any chars). Besides how it's constructed and that it's more efficient than the lookbehind-variant the result is supposed to be the same.

@bobblebubble The expression is not [a-z\d], it is [a-z]+\d+. The size of each subexpression match is not known, but the sum must be 7.

@DYZ I see... my lookahead-variant does not work as supposed to. The pattern would match such as a1b12345. Thank you for pointing that out, interesting task anyways!

@DYZ It hink the flaw can be fixed by adding another condition to disallow a number|non-number border within the distance, making it: ^(?=\D{1,6}\d)(?!.{1,5}\d\D)([a-z\d]{7})(.+) or a shorter variant: ^(?!\d{7}|.{0,5}\d\D)([a-z\d]{6}\d)(.+) (if a regex-solution is needed and lookbehind available, the answer of @TedLyngmo is certainly more comfortable to cope with)

One more unconventional idea without lookbehind: ^(?=.{7}(.+))([a-z]+\d+)\1$ (in this one the groups are switched). I'm unsure yet, if it has any flaws.

@Thefourthbird Very nice one! This looks to be the most efficient  one yet. ✨

@bobblebubble I think all of your last 3 tries work.

Thank you for testing this so far. I already surrendered in desperation but it gives hope to read! At least we got many choices now to solve it even with just lookahead (I read something that standard regex in c++ supports ECMAScript regex scope but no lookbehind? I'm being unclear about this).

Don't do it all with a regular expression. Use std::string::substr() to split the input into two substrings, the first 7 characters and the rest. Then check that the first substring matches the regexp ^[a-z]+\d+$.

Sometimes it's so easy to miss the obvious.  Speaking of, you missed the $ on your regexp - you don't want it to match junk on the end.

Here's one idea combining both negative and positive lookbehinds:
^([a-z]+\d+)(?<!.{8})(?<=.{7})(.+)
             ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^
                a        b


a - Negative lookbehind for 8 characters
b - Positive lookbehind for 7 characters

Demo on regex101.
C++ example using boost::regex since it's capable of lookarounds and std::regex is currently not:
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    boost::regex re(R"aw(^([a-z]+\d+)(?<!.{8})(?<=.{7})(.+))aw",
                    boost::regex_constants::ECMAScript);

    std::vector<std::string> strs{
        "hello12345",  //
        "a12345678",   //
        "ab12345678",  //
        "abc1234567",  //
        "abcd123456",  //
        "abcde12345",  //
        "abcdef1234",  //
        "abcdefg234",  //
        "a2cdef1234",  //
        "abcdefg1234", //
        "123456789"    //
    };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    for(auto& test : strs) {
        boost::smatch what;
        bool got_match = boost::regex_match(test, what, re);
        std::cout << test << '\t' << got_match << '\n';
        if(got_match) {
            std::cout << " [\"" << what[1] << "\", \"" << what[2] << "\"]\n";
        }
    }
}

Output:
hello12345      true
 ["hello12", "345"]
a12345678       true
 ["a123456", "78"]
ab12345678      true
 ["ab12345", "678"]
abc1234567      true
 ["abc1234", "567"]
abcd123456      true
 ["abcd123", "456"]
abcde12345      true
 ["abcde12", "345"]
abcdef1234      true
 ["abcdef1", "234"]
abcdefg234      false
a2cdef1234      false
abcdefg1234     false
123456789       false

As noted by bobble bubble in a comment, this can even be simplified further by anchoring the positive lookbehind and skip the negative lookbehind:
^([a-z]+\d+)(?<=^.{7})(.+)
                ^
              anchor added

C++ demo

Why not anchor the positive lookbehind to ^ start and drop the negative? (regex101)

@bobblebubble Brilliant simplification! Thanks!

If lookbehind is not available, an alternative is to use a lookahead and capture everything after a part of specified length n inside. Later on to check the initial part, the captured part \1 is appended after it. Remember that lookahead groups are atomic, hence there won't disturb any backtracking.
The underlying idea is ^(?=.{n}(.*))check\1$. So for your current task the pattern will be:
^(?=.{7}(.+))([a-z]+\d+)\1$

See this demo at regex101 - The performance is not too bad, it's compatbile and gets the job done. Further it's generic and can be easily adpated to whatever length and pattern is needed.

If the first part of the match should be 1 or more digits, and the second part of the match should be one or more characters a-z, you know that the first match is a char a-z and the last match is a digit.
If n is 7 then there are 5 characters in between for which you can specify a rule that on position 2-6 there can be no occurrence of a digit followed by a char a-z
Using boost::regex you might use:
^([a-z](?![a-z0-9]{0,4}\d[a-z])[a-z\d]{5}\d)(.+)

The pattern matches:

^ Start of string
( Capture group 1

[a-z] Match the first char a-z
(?! Negative lookahead, assert that directly to the right of the current position is not:

[a-z0-9]{0,4}\d[a-z] Match 0-4 accepted characters followed by a digit and a-z


) Close the lookahead
[a-z\d]{5}\d Match 5 times the allowed characters followed by a digit


) Close group 1
(.+) Capture 1 or more chars in group 2

Regex demo

If the "word" at the beginning ends on a digit, you might use word boundary in a positive lookahead:
^(?=[a-z]+[0-9]+\b)([a-z0-9]{6}[0-9])(.+)

Regex demo
